# How to conditionally bind_property () two properties?

Tags: gtk, glib, vala, genie

It’s been a while since I've been not successful on solving this problem. It is an exercise where a Spin Button and a Scale are constantly synced while a check button is ticked. But, when the check button is not active, both the scale and the spin are free to get any values.

In a previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/59260783?noredirect=1) it was suggested to use bind_property method, and that really works well when you want both the spin and the scale synced all the time. However, when one need to link it to the activity (or lack thereof) of the check button it does not work. The second time one clicks the check button, the program hangs.

Here is how far I’ve got:

```
[indent=4]
uses
    Gtk

class TestWindow:Window

    _spin:SpinButton
    _scale:Scale
    _check:CheckButton

    construct ()
        //General aspects of the window
        title = "Spin and scale"
        window_position = WindowPosition.CENTER
        destroy.connect( main_quit )

        //create the spin button
        spinAdjustment:Adjustment = new Adjustment( 50, 0, 100, 1, 5, 0 )
        scaleAdjustment:Adjustment = new Adjustment( 50, 0, 100, 1, 5, 0 )
        _spin = new SpinButton( spinAdjustment, 1.0, 1 )

        //create the horizontal scale
        _scale = new Scale( Orientation.HORIZONTAL, scaleAdjustment );

        //create the check button
        _check =  new CheckButton.with_label ( "Sync both scales!" )
        _check.set_active(true)
        _check.toggled.connect( toggled )

        // organize it in a box
        var box = new Box( Orientation.VERTICAL, 0 )
        box.pack_start( _spin, true, true, 0 )
        box.pack_start( _scale, true, true, 0 )
        box.pack_start( _check, true, true, 0 )
        add( box )


    def toggled ()
        if (_check.active)
            _spin.adjustment.bind_property( "value", _scale.adjustment, "value",BindingFlags.SYNC_CREATE | BindingFlags.BIDIRECTIONAL )

init
    Gtk.init( ref args )
    var test = new TestWindow()
    test.show_all()
    Gtk.main()
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to link the binding to the checkbutton in such a way that it only syncs while it is pressed? Should I move on an try to find any other strategies to solve the problem?

Thanks

Comment: I changed your question title, because this follow up question is not about the original problem, but about the bind_property behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To undo the binding, you have to call the `unbind` method of the `Binding` that is returned by the `bind_property` method:

```
    _binding:Binding

    construct ()
        // ...
        _check.toggled.connect( toggled )
        _check.set_active(true)
        // ...

def toggled ()
    // If there was a binding object before
    if (_binding != null)
        // .. unbind it
        _binding.unbind ()
        // and set it to null to indicate "not bound" state
        _binding = null
    // Bind if necessary
    if (_check.active)
        _binding = _spin.adjustment.bind_property( "value", _scale.adjustment, "value",BindingFlags.SYNC_CREATE | BindingFlags.BIDIRECTIONAL )
```

To do it manually you can use the `value_changed` event:

```
    construct ()
        // ...
        _spin.value_changed.connect (spin_value_changed)
        _scale.value_changed.connect (scale_value_changed)
        _check.toggled.connect (check_toggled)
        _check.set_active(true)
        // ...

    def spin_value_changed ()
        // Only sync, when checkbox is set
        if (_check.active)
            // Avoid circle, only set if different
            if (_scale.get_value () != _spin.get_value ())
                _scale.set_value (_spin.get_value())

    def scale_value_changed ()
        // Only sync, when checkbox is set
        if (_check.active)
            // Avoid circle, only set if different
            if (_scale.get_value () != _spin.get_value ())
                _spin.set_value (_scale.get_value())

    def check_toggled ()
        spin_value_changed ()
```

Comment: A call to `bind_property` returns a [GLib.Binding](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gobject-2.0/GLib.Binding) object, which has an `unbind` method. So I don't think unbinding is the problem. What is harder is maintaining a record of the state, that is whether it is bound or unbound, in an elegant way. I think avoiding `null`s in code is a good practice and adding an additional boolean just to hold state is inelegant. Ideally the constructor would create the binding object, then calls to `unbind` and `rebind` would be made. Only `rebind` doesn't exist.

Comment: Using `null` is ok as long as it's handled properly, I added an example using unbind as well.